# if not trigger inside object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Object array does not execute the "if" when call a method with the forEach but when I move the if inside of the forEach it works, I am trying to figure out why is not trigger the if inside the object when run the forEach.

There is a var (responseFlag) with the default value (false) so if you need to change the html render just change it (true/false) when the button is clicked.

```js
    var responseFlag = false,
    targetRender = document.getElementById('targethtml'),
    templateTrue = '<h2>true</h2>',
    templateFalse = '<h2>false</h2>';
    
    // 
    objDef = {
        "objDefs" : [
            {
                "UIhtml": responseFlag == true ? templateTrue : templateFalse // does not works
                // "UIhtml": responseFlag // this works
            }
        ]
    };

    // 
    UI_exc = {
        outputResult: function() {
            objDef.objDefs.forEach(function(key, value){
                targetRender.innerHTML = 
                // responseFlag == true ? templateTrue : templateFalse // this works
                key.UIhtml // does not works
                console.log(responseFlag)
            });

        },
        clickAction: function() {
            document.getElementById('goRender').addEventListener("click", function(){
                responseFlag = true // 
                console.log(responseFlag);
                UI_exc.outputResult()
            });
        }
    };

    UI_exc.clickAction();
```

```html
<button id="goRender">Click</button>
<div id="targethtml">[ N ]</div>
```

Comment: Can you define what "_does not work_" actually means? What are you expecting as a result?

Comment: html does not update (based on var responseFlag = true/false) after onclick, "if" does just return false html template... check console and html response please.

Comment: You're using strings instead of booleans, maybe unwrapping true/flase from quotes helps?

Comment: Unfortunately does not work, the problem is not type of true/false (strings or booleans), the "if" is not trigger when call at the forEach so no matter if true or false, "if" does not trigger to validate the output result (template html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I guess is that object is initialized and the UIhtml property is assigned there, I think you should change `UIhtml` to a function and then call it:

```
... = key.UIhtml()
console.log(responseFlag)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right "if" is not working because is no call, it's just initialized. Turning UIhtml into function and call it is a good approach. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

When creating object literals, the declared properties is not a string, rather it is a just a reference to some value e.g strings, numbers, booleans, objects...

Change the "UIhtml" to UIhtml.

Read this documentation for more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: The keys of the objects are always strings, it's fine, though mostly unnecessary, to wrap a key in quotes.

Comment: Does not works if you remove the quotes. I agree with @Teemu